# How to read text file seperated by multiple characters in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, bcp

I have a file in .bcp format and try to read it. The rows are seperated by "|;;|". A row may extend over several lines in the file.

`rdd = sc.textFile("test.bcp")` splits the file into lines, but I need it serparated by "|;;|". How can I do this without changing the Hadoop configuration?

Example `.bcp`:

```
A1|;|B1|;|C1|;|
D1|;;|A2|;|B2|;|
C2|;|D2|;;|
```

should be converted to:
`[["A1", "B1", "C1", "D1"], ["A2", "B2", "C2", "D2"]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a custom delimiter with multiple characters change the hadoop configuration:

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

# let hadoop separate files by our custom delimiter
conf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", '|;;|')

# create RDD of .bcp file
rows = sc.textFile('/PATH/TO/FILE/test.bcp')  # split file into rows
rows = rows.map(lambda row: row.split('|;|'))  # split rows into columns

# reset hadoop delimiter
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "\n")
```